# Oracle changing decimal values on insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle8i

So, I'm having some trouble with Oracle doing this strange thing with my decimal number values that I'm insertting into it.  I have the oracle field value as "Number", and the number I'm insertting is a float from my C# back-end code.  I've tracked the value in my program all the way until it gets insertted into the database. Say you try to insert "1.2"?  The value is still 1.2 all the way to getting insertted, but once it's in the database, it turns into "1.20000004768372".  All my decimal values do this, either a tiny amount over or under, and I can't find any rhyme or reason why.

Detail wise, this is done on an old Oracle 8i database, with my code being asp.net/C#.  But like I said, I'm pretty sure it isn't the program doing this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure it isn't the program doing this."_ - It is. Don't use `float` in your code, use `decimal`. Obligatory [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). See also [IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic rounding error in c# and javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503157/ieee-754-floating-point-arithmetic-rounding-error-in-c-sharp-and-javascript).

Comment: Oh wow.  I can't believe I didn't know that beforehand.  Thank you kindly for teaching me something pretty darn important.  (Of course, this also resolved my problem).

Comment: Addendum:  of course, single- and double-precision floats are essential when you are doing technical and scientific programming.  Just make sure you always remember what precision you're working in.  In the business world you're usually aiming at dollars and cents, so stay in decimal.