# javascript round decimals till two

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, math

Working on a form where I am doing a minus from two forms and showing the result in the third one. The problem is when I am for example doing: 0,79 - 0,43 the result becomes: 0,36000000000000004.

So wondering if it's possible to round it to two decimals ?

`Jsfiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/eYj8B/12/

[image]

Comment: THIS WILL HELP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503157/ieee-754-floating-point-arithmetic-rounding-error-in-c-sharp-and-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) does that

```
output.val(value.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/eYj8B/13/)

Comment: Superb! Thanks for fastest answar I have ever seen! :)

Comment: I think Roko was even faster, not sure why he deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Use Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```