# VB Form won't detect and use stored numbers in variables

Tags: vb.net, forms, algorithm, variables, energy

I'm writing a simple VB form that calculates the cost of an electricity bill. The source code is below:

```
Private Sub BtnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalculate.Click

        Dim LowUnits As Integer
        'LowUnits is the cost per unit if the integer is lower than [Difference Variable]
        Dim HighUnits As Integer
        'HighUnits is the cost per unit if the integer is higher than [Difference Variable]
        Dim FixedFee As Integer
        'This is the fixed infrastructure fee that all providers charge alongside unit cost
        Dim Difference As Integer
        'Number of units before a premium price [High Units Variable] is charged
        Dim UnitNo As Integer
        'Number of Units that is inputted
        Dim Price As Double


        UnitNo = UnitBox.Text

        If RdoEE.Checked = True Then
            LowUnits = 0.04
            HighUnits = 0.06
            FixedFee = 10
            Difference = 500

        ElseIf RdoPG.Checked = True Then
            LowUnits = 0.04
            HighUnits = 0.06
            FixedFee = 15
            Difference = 600

        ElseIf RdoBG.Checked = True Then
            LowUnits = 0.03
            HighUnits = 0.05
            FixedFee = 20
            Difference = 500

        End If

        If UnitNo <= Difference Then
            Price = 1
            Price = Price * UnitNo
            Price = UnitNo * LowUnits
            Price = Price + FixedFee
        Else
            'Price = ((((Price + 1) * UnitNo) * HighUnits) + FixedFee)

        End If


        MsgBox("Your cost is £" & Price & "")



    End Sub
End Class
```

The program works as such:
You input the no. of electrical units per month, select a provider (that has different rates alongside a fixed infrastructure fee) and this outputs a total cost.
The problem i'm having is that the program doesn't seem to detect the cost of the units and store them in the Price variable, and only includes the fixed fee and doesn't calculate the units. I haven't done error handling so far as my focus is to get the program to work, which is a priority for me.

The criteria I must meet is:
"Write a program that calculates the cost of units for a provider and output the total cos for the customer. The program must give a selection of 3 different providers (EDF Energy, PowerGen and British Gas) and must output the total cost.
EDF energy charges £0.04/unit up to 500 units, then £0.06/unit above 500 units, including a £10 fixed infrastructure fee. PowerGen charges £0.04/unit up to 600 units, then £0.06/unit above 600 units, including a £15 fixed infrastructure fee. British Gas charges £0.03/unit, then £0.05/unit after 500 units, including a £20 fixed infrastructure cost."

Comment: Not your direct problem, but using `If someVar = True Then` is unnecessary and considered bad style.  Just use `If someVar Then`.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file.  Now the compiler tells you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing fractional values (e.g. `0.04`) in `Integer` values, that's your problem, and VB.NET isn't warning you about the loss of precision.

Change your local-variables from `Integer` to `Decimal` - when working with currency values always prefer `Decimal` over `Double` [because simple values like `0.1` cannot be accurately represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503157/ieee-754-floating-point-arithmetic-rounding-error-in-c-sharp-and-javascript). Or better yet: use integers but use the Penny as the base value instead of the Pound (so `1` == £0.01 and `100` == £1).

A few other tips:

- Local values should use `camelCase` casing, not `TitleCase`.
- Don't use Hungarian Notation, it is now considered bad-practice (and forbidden in many codebases). It is a relic of times before modern compilers and editors. However suffixing names with an indication of their UI component is still acceptable (so consider `britishGasRadioButton` instead of `RdoBG`).
- Enable `Option Strict` in VB.NET. If this option is enabled you will get compiler warnings and errors about narrowing operations, which is what you're experiencing when you try to narrow `Double` values to `Int32` values.
- You don't need to check `= True` for values that are already boolean, so `If RdoEE.Checked = True` can be simplified to just `If edfEnergyRadio.Checked Then`

Comment: U.K. energy suppliers are very likey to have rates like 3.7p/unit, so I suggest the Decimal type would be more suitable than using integers for pennies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

That would highlight a problem with your code:

```
Dim lowUnits As Integer
'...
lowUnits = 0.04
```

Can you see that you are trying to assign a floating-point value to a variable of Integer type? Visual Studio would have put a wavy red line under `0.04` and given you a message that "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'."

However, when dealing with numbers as currency, it is usually a Good Idea to use the Decimal data type because it does not have the same rounding errors as representing exact decimal numbers as a Double has.

There is a fairly comprehensive guide regarding using floating-point numbers in computer programming at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

So, the answer is to declare and use:

```
Dim lowUnits As Decimal
'...
lowUnits = 0.04D
```

where the `D` suffix tells the compiler that 0.04 is a Decimal.